# How to control Arduino board or stand alone AVR using serial?

Tags: c, ruby, arduino, microcontroller

I know how to program an AVR using a programmer.  I am now wanting to learn Ruby and I thought it might be fun interacting with an Arduino or just an Attiny85 directly from the serial port.

I am kind of new to this stuff.  Is there a way to control LEDs, servos and other components without burning a program directly to the AVR chip?

Would it make sense to write a Ruby program that connects to the AVR or Arduino through a serial connection and controls components?  I didn't know if this was possible.  Any ideas on how this can be done?  I see that there is a serial port gem for Ruby.  Would this be a good starting point?

I didn't know if this would be a good idea with Ruby.

Comment: https://playground.arduino.cc/Interfacing/Ruby

Comment: Thank you.  I got this working quickly for my Arduino Uno.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to flash the AVR with a program that interprets commands coming over serial from your Ruby program and takes the desired action.

One option is the Firmata protocol. There is a Firmata Arduino library:

https://github.com/firmata/arduino

Some Firmata client libraries for Ruby are listed at that [link](https://github.com/firmata/arduino#firmata-client-libraries). I haven't used it but that seems like a fast way to achieve your goal, though you may have more fun designing your own command protocol and writing the microcontroller firmware from scratch.